# Page items sliding in in metro style apps

Tags: animation, microsoft-metro, slide, items

I'm experimenting with creating a metro style app with Visual Studio 2012, I am not the most experienced designer but one thing with my applications is confusing me.

I have been working with 'basic pages' instead of blank ones for the different pages in my application for design consistency, however it seems that these 'basic pages' have a strange behaviour. Every item I place on the page (buttons, text boxes, etc) will all slide in one by one when the page opens. For example if I run the application and navigate to a page with 10 buttons, it will do a brief animation where each button will slide in from the right side to the left side. When dealing with a large number of items on one page this can take a lot of time as each item slides in seperatley.

Looking at the properties for each item I have been able to change the direction it slides in while loading the page by changing the flow direction. Also with a bit of research I am thinking it could potentially be due to either the metro style 'enterPage' or 'enterContent' animations, though I can not be certain.

I have tried to experiment and figure this out, and search to find out what causes this so I can modify it (Ideally I would like to just group items together to slide in with each other) however it's kind of a difficult thing to search with vague words, so I'm asking here.

What is causing this and how might I go about modifying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a bit of experimentation I figured out that putting all my page content inside a grid made them all come in at once like I wanted. I probably should have tried that earlier but everything was already inside an outer grid for the page, so I thought that woulda handled it.

I don't quite understand it fully, but that works for now.

Answer (score 0):

EnterPage shouldn't be sequencing the animations. They do offset some of the animations of a number of elements, but it shouldn't be each one sequentially.

Are you using WinJS navigation?

Comment: My application is a C# xaml application, I'm using this.Frame.Navigate to navigate between pages with C#